# Confusing tag completion

Tags: bug, tags

When searching for the right tag while asking a question, I realized a strange thing, making me think it's a bug:

I had asked a question related to HTTP status codes, so I entered "http" to see what kind of tags are suggested (completed).
I was kind of surprised that there seemingly weren't  any "http-status"-like tags, making me wonder whether I should add one.

However, when I typed "http-s" there were suddenly several HTTP status tags suggested, making me wonder:
*Shouldn't they have been suggested initially, too?* (`http-headers` was suggested, but no `http-status`)

Here's an example screen that I saw:

[image: Suggested HTTP tags]

Comment: Not a bug - it's a feature. It suggests synonums that also include HTTP - see at the bottom of [[tag:apache]] it says "**http**d" and for [[tag:servlets]] there is "**http**servletrequest" and "**http**servletresponse" which are tag synonyms.

Comment: It is, however, a very poorly presented feature. As with many other parts of the site, the UX is garbage, the company is aware (there are _plenty_ of reports elsewhere), and you probably need  [a large following on Twitter or another platform](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318341/332043) to get them to even consider trying to improve UX here.

Comment: What's confusing is that adding a hyphen after `http` *does not* display any more tags like `http-status` (which actually exists). So how can such system help the user to find the correct tags? Start with `status` instead of `http`?

Comment: I always thought that "talking about" and "working on" are two different things, and I thought that twitter is for people who like the former. However in the past I had made the experience that a problem reported to paid support got less attention than a problem reported in a newsgroup.  Maybe support did not talk with the developers, but developers read the newsgroup. Strange world...